# Images in a mobile adapted website?

Tags: wordpress, mobile-website

Im creating a mobile adapted Wordpress website. Im using media queries to link to a mobile css file if viewed on a mobile device. When Im posting posts in my blog the images will obviously be to large for the mobile screen. How should I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can scale your images by using below css.

```
img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

If you have not used viewport in you head tag then use this one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
```

The above code will scale the site in device viewport, If you want to stop zoom set user-scalable=No

Comment: If I do that the whole image will still be loaded which will slow my site down

Comment: @Micheal i have just updated the viewport code if you have not used or your viewport code is not similar please try this one.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution is to create 'buckets' for different screen sizes and use different background images based on media queries.

For example, you could create 4 buckets with image widths:

- 400px for 300-500px
- 800px for 500-800px
- 1200px for 800-1200px
- 1400px for 1200px+

In CSS, you could create media queries like so:

```
#elem {
    max-width: 100%;
}
@media all and (min-width: 300px) and (max-width: 500px) {
    #elem {
        background: url(../images/logo-400.jpg) left center no-repeat;
    }
}
@media all and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 800px) {
    #elem {
        background: url(../images/logo-800.jpg) left center no-repeat;
    }
}
@media all and (min-width: 800px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    #elem {
        background: url(../images/logo-1200.jpg) left center no-repeat;
    }
}
@media all and (min-width: 1200px) {
    #elem {
        background: url(../images/logo-1400.jpg) left center no-repeat;
    }
}
```

Using both 'min-width' and 'max-width' ensures that your device downloads only the images which fit the particular 'bucket'.